# printf with %a does not seem to produce a hexadecimal number

Tags: c, hex, printf

I have been told that "%a" used in C's printf would display hexadecimal format of a number.  To test it, I print out the representation of 2^10:

```
 printf ("%a", pow(2.0,10));
```

which gives

```
0x1p+10
```

I am confused because the exponent part "+10" looks more like a decimal format rather than a hexadecimal format. A hexadecimal format should have been `1pA`. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct, that format is called hexadecimal for `double`s.

The man page says:

> For `a` conversion, the `double` argument is converted to hexadecimal 
>   notation (using the letters `abcdef`) in the style `[-]0xh.hhhp[+-]d` [...] 
>   the exponent consists of a positive or negative sign followed by a
>   decimal number representing an exponent of 2.

So it's correct that while the mantissa is in hex, the exponent is still decimal.